# quantity box not updating PHP

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

this is part of my customised code for virtuemart. the issue is with the quantity box. basically, a user is able to update the value for the first item in the cart, but any items after that cannot be changed for some reason. it just throws back the number "1": how can i fix it?

```
<?php
$i = 1;
//      vmdebug('$this->cart->products',$this->cart->products);
foreach ($this->cart->products as $pkey => $prow) {
    ?>

<div>
<div style="border-bottom:1px solid #f2f2f2;padding-top:12px;padding-bottom:12px;">
<div style="display:table-cell;width:345px;">
<?php if ($prow->virtuemart_media_id) { ?>
        <span class="cart-images">
                         <?php
            if (!empty($prow->image)) {
                echo $prow->image->displayMediaThumb ('', FALSE);
            }
            ?>
                        </span>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php echo JHTML::link ($prow->url, $prow->product_name) . $prow->customfields; ?>
</div>

<div style="display:table-cell;width:75px;text-align:center;">
    <?php
        //                  vmdebug('$this->cart->pricesUnformatted[$pkey]',$this->cart->pricesUnformatted[$pkey]['priceBeforeTax']);
        echo $this->currencyDisplay->createPriceDiv ('basePriceVariant', '', $this->cart->pricesUnformatted[$pkey], FALSE);
        //                  echo $prow->salesPrice ;
        ?>
</div>
<div style="display:table-cell;width:95px;text-align:center;">
        <div style="display:inline-block;"><form action="<?php echo JRoute::_ ('index.php'); ?>" method="post" class="inline" id="quantity-update">
            <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_virtuemart"/>
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="quantity-input-checkout" size="2" maxlength="2" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $prow->quantity ?>"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="view" value="cart"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="task" value="update"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="cart_virtuemart_product_id" value="<?php echo $prow->cart_item_id  ?>"/></div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;margin-left:6px;"><a href="javascript:{}" onclick="document.getElementById('quantity-update').submit(); return false;" class="tip" title="Update the product quantity in the cart." id="store_cart_refresh" style="margin-right:7px;"><span class="alt"></span></a>
        </form>
        <a class="tip" title="Remove this product from the cart." href="<?php echo JRoute::_ ('index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=cart&task=delete&cart_virtuemart_product_id=' . $prow->cart_item_id) ?>" id="store_cart_delete"><span class="alt"></span></a></div>
</div>


<div style="display:table-cell;width:100px;text-align:center;">
<?php echo "<span class='priceColor2'>" . $this->currencyDisplay->createPriceDiv ('taxAmount', '', $this->cart->pricesUnformatted[$pkey], FALSE, FALSE, $prow->quantity) . "</span>" ?>



        <?php
        if (VmConfig::get ('checkout_show_origprice', 1) && !empty($this->cart->pricesUnformatted[$pkey]['basePriceWithTax']) && $this->cart->pricesUnformatted[$pkey]['basePriceWithTax'] != $this->cart->pricesUnformatted[$pkey]['salesPrice']) {
            echo '<span class="line-through">' . $this->currencyDisplay->createPriceDiv ('basePriceWithTax', '', $this->cart->pricesUnformatted[$pkey], TRUE, FALSE, $prow->quantity) . '</span><br />';
        }
        echo $this->currencyDisplay->createPriceDiv ('salesPrice', '', $this->cart->pricesUnformatted[$pkey], FALSE, FALSE, $prow->quantity) ?>
</div>
</div>


</div>
<?php } ?>
<?php
    $i = ($i==1) ? 2 : 1;
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The input name is quantity... it should be something like quantity_id so quantity_1, quantity_2 etc otherwise it may be difficult to grab the values on the backend in the right order.